# Fast K-step discounting in numpy/scipy/python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

x has shape [batch_size, n_time] where the batches are independent

If k=3, d=discount_rate. Pseudocode:

```
x[:,i] = x[:,i] + x[:,i+1]*(d**1) + x[:,i+2]*(d**2) + x[:,i+3]*(d**3)
```

Here's working code, but it's very slow. I'll be executing this function millions of times, so I'm hoping for a faster implementation

```
import numpy as np

def k_step_discount(x, k, discount_rate):
    n_time = x.shape[1]
    k_include_cur = k + 1 # k excludes current timestep
    for i in range(n_time):
        k_cur = min(n_time - i, k_include_cur) # prevent out of bounds
        for j in range(1, k_cur):
            x[:, i] += x[:, i+j] * (discount_rate ** j)
    return x

x = np.array([
    [0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,2,3,4,5.]
])

y = k_step_discount(x+0, k=2, discount_rate=.9)
print('x\n{}\ny\n{}'.format(x, y))


>> x
   [[ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
    [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]]
>> y
   [[  0.     0.81   0.9    1.     0.     0.  ]
    [  2.52   5.23   7.94  10.65   8.5    5.  ]]
```

A scipy function that's similar is:

```
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0,0,0,1,0,0.]])
discount_rate = .9

y = np.flip(scipy.signal.lfilter([1], [1, -discount_rate], np.flip(x+0, 1), axis=1), 1)
print('x\n{}\ny\n{}'.format(x, y))
>> x
   [[ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]]
>> y
   [[ 0.729  0.81   0.9    1.     0.     0.   ]]
```

However, it discounts until the end of n_time rather than only for k steps

I'm also interested in K-step discounting without batches, if that'd be easier/faster

```
import numpy as np

def k_step_discount_no_batch(x, k, discount_rate):
    n_time = x.shape[0]
    k_include_cur = k + 1 # k excludes current timestep
    for i in range(n_time):
        k_cur = min(n_time - i, k_include_cur) # prevent out of bounds
        for j in range(1, k_cur):
            x[i] += x[i+j] * (discount_rate ** j)
    return x

x = np.array([8,0,0,0,1,2.])
y = k_step_discount_no_batch(x+0, k=2, discount_rate=.9)
print('x\n{}\ny\n{}'.format(x, y))

>> x
   [ 8.  0.  0.  0.  1.  2.]
>> y
   [ 8.    0.    0.81  2.52  2.8   2.  ]
```

Similar no_batch scipy function

```
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np

x = np.array([8,0,0,0,1,2.])    
discount_rate = .9

y = scipy.signal.lfilter([1], [1, -discount_rate], x[::-1], axis=0)[::-1]
print('x\n{}\ny\n{}'.format(x, y))
>> x
   [ 8.  0.  0.  0.  1.  2.]

>> y
   [ 9.83708  2.0412   2.268    2.52     2.8      2.     ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`2D` convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) here. To get the scaling done properly, we need to create the proper `2D` kernel, which would be a flipped version of the powered-scaled numbers of `discount_rate`. This is in accordance with the definition of `convolution`, in which kernel is *slided* in the flipped order against the input data and its elements are scaled with those kernel ones and summed up, as precisely done in this case.

Thus, the implementation would be simply  -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2d
import numpy as np

def k_step_discount(x, k, discount_rate, is_batch=True):
    if is_batch:
        kernel = discount_rate**np.arange(k+1)[::-1][None]
        return conv2d(x,kernel)[:,k:]
    else:
        kernel = discount_rate**np.arange(k+1)[::-1]
        return np.convolve(x, kernel)[k:]
```

Sample run -

```
In [190]: x
Out[190]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.]])

# Proposed method
In [191]: k_step_discount_conv2d(x, k=2, discount_rate=0.9)
Out[191]: 
array([[  0.  ,   0.81,   0.9 ,   1.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [  2.52,   5.23,   7.94,  10.65,   8.5 ,   5.  ]])

# Original loopy method
In [192]: k_step_discount(x, k=2, discount_rate=.9)
Out[192]: 
array([[  0.  ,   0.81,   0.9 ,   1.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [  2.52,   5.23,   7.94,  10.65,   8.5 ,   5.  ]])
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [206]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,1000)).astype(float)

In [207]: %timeit k_step_discount_conv2d(x, k=2, discount_rate=0.9)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 ms per loop

In [208]: %timeit k_step_discount(x, k=2, discount_rate=.9)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.83 ms per loop
```

With bigger `k's` :

```
In [215]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,1000)).astype(float)

In [216]: %timeit k_step_discount_conv2d(x, k=20, discount_rate=0.9)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.44 ms per loop

In [217]: %timeit k_step_discount(x, k=20, discount_rate=.9)
10 loops, best of 3: 44.8 ms per loop
```

Thus, expect huge speedups with bigger `k's`!

---

**Further boost**

As suggested by [`@Eric`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745570/fast-k-step-discounting-in-numpy-scipy-python#comment74538122_43745961), we could also leverage [`scipy.ndimage.filters's 1D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve1d.html) here.

For a proper comparison listing both with Scipy's `2D` and `1D` convolution methods -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve1d as conv1d

def using_conv2d(x, k, discount_rate):
    kernel = discount_rate**np.arange(k+1)[::-1][None]
    return conv2d(x,kernel)[:,k:]

def using_conv1d(x, k, discount_rate):
    kernel = discount_rate**np.arange(k+1)[::-1]
    return conv1d(x,kernel, mode='constant', origin=k//2)
```

Timings -

```
In [100]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,1000)).astype(float)

In [101]: out1 = using_conv2d(x, k=20, discount_rate=0.9)
     ...: out2 = using_conv1d(x, k=20, discount_rate=0.9)
     ...: 

In [102]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[102]: True

In [103]: %timeit using_conv2d(x, k=20, discount_rate=0.9)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.27 ms per loop

In [104]: %timeit using_conv1d(x, k=20, discount_rate=0.9)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop
```

Comment: `scipy.ndimage.convolve1d` is probably more appropiate here than a 2d convolution, as it expresses the intent better

Comment: @Eric Thanks! Definite improvement there. Edited post accordingly.

Comment: your `origin` looks odd to me

Comment: @Eric With `origin=k//2`, it basically shifts the kernel such that it starts at the current element as needed for this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I expected it to need to be zero. Clearly what you have is correct though, as it passes the OPs tests